# Did English ever have an informal version of “we”

Tags: pronouns, history

Related question: [Did English ever have a formal version of "you"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/did-english-ever-have-a-formal-version-of-you)

In Portuguese (and probably other languages as well), similar to what happens with the second-person, there are two words for "we": "nós" (formal) and "a gente" (informal, only used in colloquial speech). Both pronouns have the same meaning: they refer to the person who is talking and can include the hearer and/or other people.

Did English ever have this feature?

Comment: There's slang like "us guys..."  "Us guys would like some beer!"

Comment: I thought in Brazilian Portuguese they *always* used "a gente".  Honestly, never noticed "nós".  I was even told not to use it.  Or maybe this is applicable only to Portugal?

Comment: @AlainPannetier: They told me in school never to use the passé simple, because it was "never used in speech". But then I met a Frenchman...

Comment: @AlainPannetier: Not always. Although it is less common, "nós" is sometimes used. In a sentence like "nós somos os melhores jogadores" ("we are the best players"),  the alternative "*a gente é os melhores jogadores" sounds "wrong".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe English has ever *systematically* encoded formality in the 1st person plural. There are of course constructions like "us lot", but thes paraphrases aren't grammaticalising formality as such and their use is always completely optional.

What you might look at is the *dual* forms of pronouns that English used to have (so there was once a difference between "wit" = "you and me, we the two of us", and "we" = "we all as a group"). By pure statistics, it's conceivable (but I've no idea if this was actually the case or what data is available) that the dual forms occurred more often in "intimate" settings and so were 'de facto' informal forms in some sense.

Also consider the practice of using "one" as an honorific alternative to "I" or "we".

Comment: Is "one" ever actually used in place of "I" or "we"?

Comment: Has "one" ever been used in place of "we"? One would have thought this wouldn't happen, since "we" is plural and "one" is singular.

Comment: @Peter, It's used that way all the time in French, but I have yet to hear it in English.

Comment: @rintaun consider: We (pron.) 2. used in formal contexts for or by a royal person, or by a writer or editor, to refer to himself or herself.