# Can you also say "Take you care" or "Take you care, too"?

Tags: greetings, synonyms

As a greeting in parting you often say "Take care" (at least in the US, I am not so sure about the UK).

Can you also say "Take you care" or answer with "Take you care, too"?

Comment: You can say it if you want.  But if you do, you may not be understood.

Comment: ...except in Norfolk, England where it's standard in the local dialect!

Comment: *"You take care [now]"* is reasonable, but *"Take you care"* isn't something any native speaker would say.

Comment: Every once in a while, I might hear, "Take care of yourself..."

Comment: I just say "You too!".  Works for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'll second *take care* as popular in the US.

As far as

> "take you care" or  "take you care, too"

this construction isn't standard.  That said,

> "you take care" and "you take care, too"

are often heard.

Comment: Not only isn't it standard, it's ungrammatical. English does not allow subject-verb inversion with non-auxiliary verbs.

Comment: @JohnLawler: bit sweeping. *Sit ye down* and *Haste ye back* may be twee, but not ungrammatical.

Comment: Modern English grammar? Thinkest thou this useful be?

Comment: *Ye* and *thee* are definitely still used in Northern England, and not just for effect.  But even if they were just used archly, it's still English Language & Usage.

Comment: Consult Yoda shall we?

Comment: @Tolerance72 would that we could, believe you me.

Comment: English grammer twas got young bill some trouble then. Ye what thinkest? His lesson he has learned?

Comment: @cornbread ninja: Nice try! But *would that we could* is a totally different construction (and *believe you me*, this aside starts with a "set phrase" that doesn't follow the syntax of modern English! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wasn't trying anything with *would that we could*, and I've learned today that [*believe you me*](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-bel2.htm) is a rather young construction.  :)

Comment: @cornbread ninja: Phew! I vaguely suspected that (I felt it was more "dialectal" than "Victorian"), which is why I deleted the word *"archaic"* that I initially wrote before *"set phrase"*. Glad I did now! Like you though, I was surprised to see just *how* recent it is.

Answer (score 4):

It is:

> (You) Take care.

I have no idea what your native tongue is. But you might be interested in the subject of [word order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_order). If you find yourself switching the order of words in a sentence (usually because you are mentally translating on the fly), then it is very likely because your native language follows a word order different from English.

Answer (score 4):

"Take care" is in the imperative, i.e. it is a command or request. "You" is assumed as the subject and not normally included. This is the same for all imperatives. "Sit down", "Pass the salt", "Bring a friend", etc., you do not include an explicit subject except in rare cases where it is needed for clarity or emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "No" you cannot say "Take you care" in any context.

In this context, "You" is implied because the construction is an imperative, and [modern English does not compose 'you' in the ways of Middle English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/did-english-ever-have-a-formal-version-of-you/9782#9782).  The correct for, is "Take care of yourself" since the subject is now explicit.

"You take care" is an imperative (order-instruction) that can gain tremendous (and socially awkward) force through *inflection*.

Colloquially, "take you care" is an expression I have most-often heard used in the 'middle US' states.  I feel that moving the "you" to from the beginning to the middle of the expression does the action of 'softening', and thus personalizing (de-formalize), the culturally-uncouth nature of an imperative construction.  Like most colloquial expressions, users are likely to bond more with speaker.

Comment: -1 Per my comment to Wade. Forget the meaningless "Boxes take care", and consider the military command *"Company... Halt!"*. As with all imperatives, there's an implied *"you"*, as *"You (the Company) Halt!"*.

Comment: The imperative is fine, but the placement of "you" in the middle is not an allowed construction.

Comment: I've removed the downvote because following the edit you're no longer saying anything I think is actually *wrong*, but I don't really think it's relevant to bring up the "reflexive" extension. In practice, when people add *"of yourself"* they normally mean something significantly different - either implying that they don't *trust* you to look after yourself without being reminded, or that you are in a particularly vulnerable state at the time.

Comment: More normally, and sounding like something a little child would say to set everyone roaring [with laughter], it would be "Company, you halt"!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an English native speaker, but I believe that "Take care" is popular – not "You take care" or "You take care, too".

What would be the point of "you"?

Comment: Go first, no, _you_ go first - same idea. Wishing the same back to the person initiating the dialogue

Comment: If someone says "take care" and you just reply "take care", it just sounds like an echo. So a person might respond "you take care" or "you take care too".

Comment: Please re-read the question. It's not about "You take care".

Comment: @Jim Balter: Don't be so sure! Firstly, OP specifically asks if he can legitimately transform his original *"Take care"* into two different versions both including the word *you*. Secondly, as should not have escaped your notice, my first sentence here is structurally identical to OP's original - it's an imperative, with *you* implied.

Comment: "Don't be so sure" -- I am well advised to be sure that the question is not about "You take care". "my first sentence" -- I was not aware that MustafaJF was your sockpuppet. ""as should not have escaped your notice" -- what has not escaped my notice is that you are very confused.

Answer (score 1):

I would likely use *and you* in a reply to take care