# Is there any reason why English doesn’t add respectful words in every sentence?

Tags: formality, politeness, political-correctness, honorifics

My mother tongue, Korean, and its neighbor Japanese have postpositions for expressing honoring the opposite in each sentence when we say to seniors or strangers if these are younger than the speaker. While English has no such postpositions or whatever that is to attached to each sentence.

Now I have a question. When you English native speakers say to seniors or strangers if these are younger than you, do you think that you are honoring the opposites by saying at times some respectful words, just like in the math we calculate A * (X + Y + Z) into A * X + A * Y + A * Z? Or is there any reason not to use the words that the two languages do?

Comment: Voting to close as non-constructive. Is there any reason why Korean and Japanese do add respectful words in every sentence?

Comment: @František Stanko: It's an interesting question & is certainly related to usage, especially for native speakers of Chinese, Japanese, & Korean when they translate their native languages into English. I'm voting to keep it open. It's clear that not everyone knows the answer.

Comment: You are wrong, sir. English very much has such words, sir. If you can't think of them, I humbly suggest that you think harder, sir. Cheerio!

Comment: @Bill Franke: Chinese has no such postpositions that the other two languages do.

Comment: @RegDwighт, do you use your sir, sir, sir, when you say in daily life? See the second paragraph i wrote and produce the proper comment.

Comment: Sir and ma'am are alive and well in Texas. They are widely used in business and family situations.

Comment: @Listen: I read the question in its entirety. I wonder why you would suggest otherwise. Or label my comments improper, for that matter. And yes, I use *sir* in daily life. As do others. If nobody used the word, it wouldn't exist.

Comment: @RegDwighт, why don't you ponder on the JR's answer, sir. Cheerio!

Comment: Listenever: I believe @RegDwighт is saying the same thing I am, more or less, albeit in a more lighthearted way.

Comment: Chinese used to have required polite forms before the Ching dynasty was overthrown in 1911, but the point is the use of [honorifics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_honorifics) & what English speakers & other Westerners consider **overly polite** language. Chinese still uses "nin" (您) instead of "ni" (你) ("you") for the elderly & socially superior. Japanese is an SOV language and naturally has postpositions. Chinese, like English, is generally SVO & generally doesn't, but some linguists claim that it's morphing into an SOV language.

Comment: I don't understand what possible relevance the distributive property of mathematics has here. Also, don't you mean "...strangers when they are *older* than the speaker..."?

Comment: English is not special in that regard, there are lots of languages that don't have any honorifics at all. Korean and Japanese are special in -having- the extra politeness words/grammar.

Comment: I tried to edit the question into shape, but gave up after realizing that about all I'm getting out of it is "why doesn't English have honorifics". Is that really all you're asking, @Listenever?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the English language, which makes it off-topic. It has to do with the culture clash of fawning toadies versus people who speak more honestly — which makes it not constructive. Just because we find kow-towing to be deeply insulting to both parties has nothing to do with the English language.

Comment: @Mitch how many languages, from how many language families, have you looked at in order to conclude that what English does is the norm, and that Korean and Japanese is the exception? (Speaking here as a native English speaker who is studying Japanese)

Comment: I think an important point that the listener is omitting is that Japanese and Korean speakers *have to* calculate politeness in every conversation they have, since there are different ways of conjugating the verbs depending on the politeness. No such process exists in English.

Comment: I've tried asking a more general question about this on Linguistics.SE. I'm not sure how it'll be received, as I only rarely ask questions there: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/correlation-between-politeness-of-a-culture-and-its-languages

Comment: Several ELU members address [Yoichi Oishi](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119/yoichi-oishi) as "Yoichi-san". I neither applaud nor deplore this - it's a personal choice. But I'm sure Yoichi himself doesn't think the less of those who *don't* address him so. ELU is after all ***English** Language & Usage*, and (notwithstanding comments from our beloved leader RegDwighт! :) the fact of the matter is that modern-day Anglophones do *not* habitually drop honorifics into "conversation". I respectfully suggest, sir, that to do so today might often be seen as *haughty/pretentious*.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: [Lots?](http://wals.info/feature/45A?s=20&z4=3000&z3=2999&z2=2998&z1=2997&tg_format=map&v1=cfff&v2=cff0&v3=cd00&v4=c00d). If we take 'politeness distinctions' to mean simply a difference in pronouns, then English got rid of that distinction by -always- using the more polite 'you' instead of the too familiar 'thou'. I couldn't find a relevant map for actual grammatical inflections for politeness, but the only one I've ever heard of is in Japanese, and none ever in all Indo-European or Semitic languages. The rest of the world I'm not sure.

Comment: @Mitch Politeness distinctions include calling someone Mister Smith, John Smith, John, Smith, Johnny, Smitty.

Comment: @tchrist: I think the OP's point is that Korean and Japanese have not just lexical distinctions (Sie/du, you/thou) but also much more ingrained grammatical distinctions like an entire inflectional system for he various levels of respect.

Comment: @tchrist: There is some very weak Sapir-Whorf going on with the grammar rules, but mostly, you just repeat the stuff and it doesn't imply sincerity or anything.

Comment: @Mitch But it is not genuine respect, only feigned.  Otherwise they would not use formal, mechanical rules.  It seems insincere.

Comment: @tchrist Doubtless our habit of first-naming almost everybody seems just as insincerely egalitarian and spuriously intimate to them. Hell, **I'm** uncomfortable with it until I've worked with someone for a matter of weeks.

Comment: @tchrist: It's just like military-speak. You respect the uniform, the rank, the office, not necessarily the person, so you say "Yes, Sir/Ma'am" or "No, Sir/Ma'am" instead of "Yeah, right" or "Fuhgeddit, dude". We have a term in Japanese for the much vaunted American "honesty": bakashoujiki (馬鹿正直) = "honest to a fault; foolishly honest; naively honest". The first two characters mean "horse" and "deer", and, more colloquially, the expression means "stupidly honest".

Comment: @tchrist  Echoing Bill Franke: my wife addresses her professors (who are mostly her age or younger) by first name off-stage, but as "Professor" in class. If I were taking those classes, I would too, and I'm older and have the same union card.

Comment: Btw, I didn't know languages had neighbors. ;)

Comment: @Kris You didn’t know that [languages have neighbors](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neighboring+languages%22&btnG=Search&client=opera&rls=en&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)!

Comment: @tchrist A better reference: "... a recursively generable distance over strings, and for a language L, we define a k-neighbor language L' as a language obtained from L by (i) adding some strings not in L each of which is at most k distant from some string in L and by (ii) deleting some strings in L each of which is at most k distant from some string not in L. Then we define a k-neighbor system of a base language class as the collection of k-neighbor languages of languages in the class, and adopt it as a hypothesis space. We give formal definitions of k-neighbor (refutable) inferability... .

Comment: Just because people from English-language cultures do not have inflectional markers for status or manners in no way implies that those cultures are ignorant of the same. Having good manners is more than having special inflectional notations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As previous answers indicate, English does have
terms that show respect.  For example, I'm in 
the habit of saying "Yes, sir," even when I 
am addressing someone younger than I.  Occasionally
I'll also say "Yes, ma'am," out of respect for 
a woman who may be near my age or older.

Don't neglect the nonverbal aspects of showing
deference and respect.  Bowing is a gesture
used in some cultures, whereas in American culture 
a simple nodding of the head will suffice 
(although even in America, someone might, in the
presence of a president, for example, bow slightly).

Proxemics, the study of the use of space to communicate
various things, including respect, tells us that
respect--in America, for example--is sometimes
revealed when people keep their distance and refrain
from unnecessary touching--by hugging, for example.

Yes, Americans in general are loath to overdo the 
showing of respect.  We're all so egalitarian in
our perspectives.  Nevertheless, Americans do show
respect in a variety of ways, albeit less
formally than, say, Koreans or Japanese.

I hope this helps.

Comment: O you give me the egalitarian view on the ways of showing respect. I couldn’t get the more helpful answer than yours. I thank you very much.

Comment: What America do you live in?

Comment: @Robusto Where they don't ask those kind of questions. lol

Comment: +1 Though I don't think people mean 'America' every time they say 'English' -- note that the OP is a Korean-speaker -- asking about the English language in its broader sense.

Answer (score 7):

It's not really an English thing, because so many cultures speak English, and each culture has its own ways of showing deference and respect. For example, there are parts of the southern U.S. where it's very common for someone in their 20s to refer to elders as "sir" or "ma'am". I've also heard a lot of enlisted soldiers and marines do the same thing (I'm not talking about how they address senior officers, I'm referring to how they address civilians.)

Several other titles exist in other "subcultures." It's not unusual for a waitress to call a customer "hun" (short for "honey"), for example. Although widely regarded as a term of affection, rather than respect, I'd bet that most of these waitresses would swear they are trying to be friendly, which could be regarded as a kind of respect.

But you are correct when you say that English, as a whole, does not have this construct built into the language. Yet there are ways to use the language to attain that same result.

Comment: People in the service industry nearly always use *sir* or *maam* to address the customer.

Answer (score 5):

The primary reason is cultural. Western languages are not steeped in Confucian culture. Filial piety and constantly overtly expressed respect for the elderly, for seniors, and for superiors are not central values in Western cultures. Most Western languages have polite forms (du & Sie in German, tu and Vous in French, for "you"), but English lost that distinction when thee and thou died a couple of hundred years ago. Still, there are polite & impolite ways to speak English. English speakers generally consider using honorifics as obsequious.

Comment: So can I understand your words as the math calculation?

Comment: Re: "English lost that distinction when thee and thou died a couple of hundred years ago." yes, that is true, but I think you've taken the wrong lesson from it [Did English ever have a formal version of 'you'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/did-english-ever-have-a-formal-version-of-you)

Comment: @Listenever *Obsequious* is one of the more careful ways of describing our impression of such. It also seems insincere, cloying, fake, and is generally considered offensive. The word *toadying* also comes to mind. It’s like somebody who wants something from you constantly showering you with false praise as though it were some sort of bribe to mollycoddle your ego. It’s totally transparent, and frankly stinks. Nobody likes a brown-noser or an ass-kisser, and that’s what this comes off as.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, you're right, and I sometimes use _toadying_ and _ass kissing_ to describe to my Taiwanese clients how Westerners (especially English speakers) view what is required "politeness" in Chinese, Japanese, and Korean. Especially when they preface **every reply** (sometimes we're talking 30 of 'em) to a reviewer criticism or comment with "Thank you for your comment". OTOH, I don't think that calling such language _obsequious_ is particularly "careful". It's just not as crude and rude and uninformed as your analysis and conclusions.

Comment: @BillFranke I forgot the part about how tiresomely dillydallying it all seems, like extra cruft that just gets in the way of things by delaying and delaying and delaying.

Comment: @Mitch: English used to have two 2nd-person pronouns, one singular (thou) and one plural (ye): "used from late 13th century also as a singular pronoun of 2nd person in nominative case including direct address, at 1st only as the **appropriate form of address to a person of high social status or not well known to the speaker** (My Lord of Gloucester, now ye grow too hot— Shakespeare) (sweet mother, do ye love the child— Alfred Tennyson) (d' ye stand there, knave, and see your master robbed— Charles Reade)" MW3UDE.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, that's also true. That's why I tell my clients to say everything as briefly and to-the-point and neutrally as possible. Say "thank you" once at the beginning and don't tell the reviewers or editors how "respected" they and their journal are because they already know and don't care about the authors' opinions on that topic. Etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Your 'clients'? You didn't specify if they are native English speaking or native Chinese speaking.

Comment: @tchrist: yes, that is the other side of the cultural coin. THose with all the variety of politeness patterns think everyone else is rude, and those that speak those without the patterns think those that use them are stuck up.

Comment: @Mitch: I did say "...to my **Taiwanese clients** how Westerners (especially English speakers...". The national language here is Mandarin Chinese. I wouldn't need to tell native speakers of English what English speakers think about excessively polite language. My 16-year-old son is culturally Taiwanese & can in one way be called a "native-speaker of English", but he's never lived in the US, so he doesn't understand American "culture". I have to explain the social & cultural value of what he translates from Chinese (his "native language") & Taiwanese (his "mother tongue") into oral English.

Comment: @BillFranke You/ye/thou is even more complicated than tchrist's complicated exposition in Mitch's link, above. Even in Sh's time the you/thou contrast was at least as much a matter of intimacy and amity as of acquaintance and rank; in the passage you quote, the speaker is Gloster's uncle - and his bitter enemy. The ye/you contrast is ambiguous: often in Sh and almost certainly 250 years later the "ye" in informal writing is merely a colloquial unstressed "you"; "d'ye stand there" is most likely what a modern BE writer would spell "dyer" and an AE writer "Dja".

Comment: @StoneyB: The contrast I mentioned was the "thou/ye" or "thou/you" contrast, not "ye/you", which are the same word spelt differently.

Comment: @BillFranke So did I, on the first one. And "you", which eventually replaced both "ye" and "thou", was originally the distinct objective case of "ye".

Answer (score 5):

While in all languages there are ways of being more or less polite, languages differ in the extent to which politeness is grammaticalized. Japanese and Korean are somewhat curious from a cross-linguistic perspective because they use different inflectional endings on verbs to show different levels of politeness. If you are speaking either of these languages, you **have to** choose a level of politeness for every sentence you say, because the verb will not be complete if one of the inflectional categories is not chosen.

Some other languages have grammatical affixes used to show politeness. In Urarina, a language spoken in Peru, an enclitic *=tɕe* must be added to the verb in conversations between members of the opposite sex, or between male in-laws. ([Olawsky 2006](http://books.google.com/books?id=c_82oPIpHKUC&pg=PA543&lpg=PA543&dq=morphological%20politeness&source=bl&ots=sMfenQgENL&sig=WsuwaDzTV1hE2QCCcfY9q9ke3Bo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FL7XUOyCBIKGqgGoz4HgBQ&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=politeness&f=false):534) Classical Nahuatl (formerly spoken in Mexico) uses a suffix *-tzin* (an honorific marker) on verbs and prepositions when someone of lower social status speaks to someone of higher social status. The word meaning "on", for example, can be said *itech* (normal), or *itechcopatzinco* (polite).

More common are languages where grammatical politeness distinctions are restricted to pronouns. This includes many languages of Europe. See the map in [WALS](http://wals.info/feature/45A?tg_format=map&v1=cfff&v2=cff0&v3=cd00&v4=c00d) to get an idea of how common it is for languages to have different forms of pronouns depending on the politeness context. English until recently distinguished between an informal second person singular pronoun *thou*, and a polite version, *you*.

In this case I think it is better to ask why Korean and Japanese *do* have special politeness-indicating inflection on their verbs than to wonder why English does not. Surely there are some cultural factors involved, but it would be hard to speculate what kind of cultural organization would be required to make a language likely to have verbal suffixes for politeness.

Comment: Maybe Koreans and Japanese are inherently more polite than everybody else?

Comment: @Mitch “Inherently”? Like in DNA? All cultures have their own idea of what does or does not constitute good manners, and you cannot judge how well-mannered representatives of one culture are using the standards of a different one. This is not a language issue.

Comment: @Mitch probably the way to put it is that at the time the verbal system(s) developed into their modern forms, Korean and Japanese people were by custom more inherently mindful of social distinctions than other communities.

Answer (score 3):

The English language has a long tradition of subverting honorifics. Robert Caro writes of the U.S. Senate in the 1940s, when courtesy was extremely formal and elaborate:

> addressing a fellow senator in the second person was still “almost an unforgivable sin. It must always be in the third person. [. . . But] Alban Berkely advised a freshman, “If you think a colleague is stupid, refer to him as ‘the able, learned and distinguished senator,’ but if you know he is stupid, refer to him as ‘the *very* able, learned and distinguished senator.’

And 350 years earlier, in *Romeo and Juliet*, the use of ‘sir’ rather exacerbates than tempers the hostility between servants of rival houses:

> *Sampson*: Nay, as they dare. I will bite my thumb at them; which is a disgrace to them, if they bear it.
>
> *Enter ABRAHAM and BALTHASAR*
>
> *Abraham*: Do you bite your thumb at us, sir?
> *Sampson*: I do bite my thumb, sir.
> *Abraham*: Do you bite your thumb at us, sir?
> *Sampson (to Gregory)*: Is the law of our side if I say ay?
> *Gregory*: No.
> *Sampson*: No, sir, I do not bite my thumb at you sir; but I bite my thumb, sir.
> *Gregory*: Do you quarrel, sir?
> *Abraham*: Quarrel, sir? No, sir.
> *Sampson*: If you do, sir, I am for you: I serve as good a man as you.
> *Abraham*: No better.
> *Sampson*: Well, sir.
> *Gregory (to Sampson)*: Say 'better'; here comes one of my master's kinsmen.
> *Sampson*: Yes, better, sir.
> *Abraham*: You lie.
> *Sampson*: Draw, if you be men! Gregory, remember thy swashing blow.
> *(They fight)*

Honorifics haven't much chance of surviving such uses as those.