# What does “We use the formal lei” mean?

Tags: meaning, italian

There was the following passage in an article written by Jhumpa Lahiliri, 2000 Pulitzer Prize winner that came under the title, “Teach yourself Italian” in [The New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/12/07/teach-yourself-italian) (December 7, 2015):

> “I’m very fond of my teacher. Although for four years we use the
>   formal *lei*, we have a close, informal relationship. We sit on a wooden
>   bench at a small table in the kitchen. I see the books on her shelves,
>   the photographs of her grandchildren.”

As I was unable to catch the meaning of “We use the formal *lei*,” I consulted English dictionaries online, and found that almost of all dictionaries provide nothing more than a definition of “lei” as “a necklace of flowers that is given to a visitor in Hawaii” like Merriam-Webster.com/dictionary does.

But a Hawaiian necklace doesn’t seem to have anything to do with learning Italian or fit well in the line, “Although for four years we use the formal lei” to me. What is “lei” here? Why is it shown in italic? Why is it the formal lei even they have an informal relationship?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Italian, not English.

Comment: @Silenus. This is an article wrtiten in English and appearing in a leading English language journal. Don't be stingy. If it's Italian, what does it mean in English?, that what I want to know.

Comment: It means "you." In English (and many languages), we use italics when we want to indicate that a word is being used metalinguistically, that is, that the word is being *mentioned* rather than *used*.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's mentioned or used to me.All I want to know is just a  meaning of the word. No more than that. Don't  waste your mouth. Give me the translation.

Comment: It means "you." Good luck.

Comment: It mean 'formal you'? What does it mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36445/discussion-between-yoichi-oishi-and-silenus).

Comment: @YoichiOishi, see also [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/did-english-ever-have-a-formal-version-of-you)

Comment: @YoichiOishi 'lei' is not an English word. Native English speakers have to look it up just like you (unless one is familiar with Romance languages and can guess).

Comment: @YoichiOishi also 'Don't waste your mouth' is a little rude sounding, especially for a mod.

Comment: As others have said, it is an Italian word. You can find more information about its use here: http://www.orbilat.com/Languages/Italian/Grammar/Italian-Verb-Forms_of_address.html

Comment: Mitch. I overlooked that Sumelic (Correction: Silenus) actually had given me the answer that ‘lei’ means “you” in his second comment. So I mistook him for not having the answer (in fact, he gave), but  comment only, and was frustrated. My apology for my misunderstanding and rudeness. Actually, I casted an up-vote and “approval” to his answer no later than I got it and found that ‘lei’ mean ‘you.’ I also deeply appreciate semelic's input on orbilat.com/Languages/Italian/Grammar, which was very informative.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the word lei in this sense is not in the lexis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not English. It's Italian. It's the formal version of "you" in Italian ([here](https://www.google.com/#q=lei+italian)).

The italics indicates that the word is being used metalinguistically, that is, that the word is being *mentioned* rather than *used*.

The author is saying that he and his teacher used the formal version of "you" even though they had an informal relationship.

Comment: In Italian, to distinguish the difference, *Lei* should be capitalized.