# What do you call the process of formally addressing someone by using honorifics?

Tags: formality, speech, titles, honorifics, forms-of-address

My native language is Macedonian, and in my language, we have a special term that describes the process of formally addressing someone. The idea is that you treat that person in plural instead of in singular, plus you also use the proper honorifics.

For example:

> Hello, Professor Mark, How are **You** today?

In the sentence above, there are three important things

1. **You** starts with capital **Y**
2. **You** in this context (if it was in Macedonian of course) would be personal pronoun for second person plural (In Macedonian it is totally different word than the one for second person singular)
3. We use the word **Professor** as an honorific/title.

For this process, or way of addressing someone formally, we have a word in the Macedonian language: **Персирање**

I would like to know the equivalent of the English Language and I couldn't find it in few online and few printed dictionary that I have had access to.

I would highly appreciate if someone finds the right word for me and also tell me more about the roles for formal addressing in the English Language (or redirect me to some article).

Thank you.

Comment: Majestic plural (Pluralis maiestatis ) : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we

Comment: There is no facility in modern English for addressing someone directly in either a singular or plural form. The (old) singular form, *how art thou*, is now archaic. Apart from that, a formal means of address using an honorific is called a *salutation*.

Comment: @Mick: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I have understood wrong, but **salutation** would be initiating a conversation with a greeting (in a polite way) but (and again if I am not wrong) **salutation** doesn't explain using the honorifics throughout the entire conversation or until the other person kindly asks us not to do that...

Comment: You are right. I'm not sure what the repeated use of honorifics as a matter of courtesy is called. It is a form of deference, but I don't know if there is a precise term. Interesting question. Let's hope that someone can provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

English has, in practical terms, lost its *[T-V distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-V_distinction)*. To be sure there are different registers, but they are indicated by things like adherence to standard as opposed to dialectical English, or using more indirect or deferential language. It is not conveyed by the choice of a separate set of pronouns as in many Indo-European languages (or in languages like Korean and Japanese, a separate set of all kinds of other words as well). You could thus ask *how are you?* of both a toddler and the prime minister equally appropriately. (Of course, [*You* was originally the polite form](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/).)

As for honorific titles, we do use them in more formal settings and especially with members of more elite circles (e.g. Doctor, Reverend, Professor), but that is simply an expression of respect and/or distance, not the employment of a distinct variety of English. I always say the only people who address me as *sir* or *mister* are those trying to sell me something.

Academics may speak of *honorific speech* or *linguistic [honorifics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B0080448542002935)* as a concept, but as modern English does not exhibit it, such terminology is not widely understood. Rather, in my experience the subject mostly comes up in terms of learning foreign languages: when to use the *plain* or *direct* or *familiar form* as opposed to the *respectful* or *honorific* or *polite form*, and so on. Often, the term is language-specific, like warning that *Höflichkeitsform* can be taken as distancing, or relief that the *vosotros form* is not used in Mexico or Central America.

Comment: Well, *honouring* is the most accurate term for it, although that encompasses a lot of attendant things like body language too :o)