# What is the possessive form of "y'all"?

Tags: single-word-requests, pronouns, possessives, contractions, you-all

I generally hear *y'alls's* used as the possessive form, but I have also heard *yourn*. Since *y'all* is a colloquial pronoun, its possessive form is basically liberated from prescriptive linguistics which would probably say that *y'all* is a contraction for *you all* and therefore must be possessivized as *of all of you*.

Do you know if there is a "standard" way to make *y'all* possessive, insofar as *y'all* usage can be considered standard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8102/what-is-the-proper-usage-of-yall-in-southern-american-dialects

Comment: Why are there two questions here that are widely divergent? Which would you like answered?

Comment: @Jsolebrand Sorry, I meant *possessive* but wrote *plural*, which doesn't make sense anyways because *y'all* is already plural. It should be fixed now.

Comment: y'all is most assuredly not plural. I've now had several people tell me I'm wrong. Go figure.

Comment: @jcolebrand When would you ever use *y'all* to refer to only one person?

Comment: @jcolbrand I agree it refers the singular entity that represents a group.  In addition it would be a contracted form of `you all` so the possesive would be your all.  Though my cousins from Tennessee say y'all's.  To me rhis is kind of like asking the the plural form of s'not (is not).  There is no correct way to say something improperly.

Comment: I would just ask someone "so are y'all going to the store then" knowing that it was only one person and only one person could possibly go. Kind of like "am I not going" but ... yeah.

Comment: Say you divided a room of friends into two even groups.  You turn to one group and ask "What are you half going to do today?"  Do we now need to invent fake pronouns and possessive forms to deal with "you-half"?  I suggest "yalf" and "yalf's".

Comment: 'standard' is not an appropriate word for this situation, better to ask what do people commonly use. The answer to that is a mix of 'your', 'yours', and 'y'alls'."Y'all's's" sounds like it shouldn't be a thing, yet, I feel like it's used.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on whether you are indicating individual or group possession.

> Did y'all get *your* coats?

*Your* is used because each person has a coat.

> Is that *y'all's* house?

*Y'all's* is used because the house is theirs collectively.  I never use *y'alls's* because *y'all* is already plural and doesn't need the *s* before the apostrophe.

For what it's worth, I'm from the Alabama and use both *y'all* and *y'all's* regularly.

Comment: I agree with the logic behind the usage of *your* to indicate individual possession, but I don't think it always happens that way in practice. As a Tennessean, I often hear *your all's* or *y'all's* in the same place. I've never seen either forms written, but one can assume that anyone willing to make such an obviously improper grammatical construct is not going to be too concerned with the placement of an apostrophe.

Comment: This is about correct. I say "about" because this is very informal, loose usage at best. I also have lived in the South and have noted wide use of "y'all" and "y'all's." Singular "y'all" is illustrative, e.g., you are talking to one person, you can ask, "Is this y'all's truck?" which implies family ownership - even though other members of the family are not present. "Yourn" sounds like an Appalachianism to me.

Comment: @The Raven: "Yourn" is mostly archaic in the UK, but still current in some Northern (rural/rustic?) dialects, I think.